# Define nested set in OPL

Tags: cplex, ilog, opl

I need to define a set of tuples that are composed of a set of tuples

```
tuple link{
   string src;
   string dest;
};
tuple route{
   {link} links
};
{route} possible_routes;
```

Another way that can represent my problem is a set of set (a set of sets of links).
The only trial that was a success is defining a set of tuples that have 
a set of strings each, but I need to extend that to a set of tuples.
Is that possible in OPL?

Answer (score 1):

Within an OPL tuple you may only use arrays of int. But you could write

```
tuple link{
   string src;
   string dest;
};

{link} possible_routes[1..2]=[{<"A","B">,<"B","C">,<"C","D">},{<"A","E">}];

execute
{
writeln(possible_routes);
}
```

Comment: I need to represent a set of routes that will contribute in an array of possible what I need is  {route} possible_routes[0..n];

Comment: int n=2;

tuple link{
   string src;
   string dest;
};

{link} possible_routes[0..n]=[{<"A","B">,<"B","C">,<"C","D">},{<"A","E">},{<"A","G">}];

execute
{
writeln(possible_routes);
}